Error: "A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly"
I'm trying to create a basic private route that is void of role permissions and restrictions at the moment and when I use the syntax that I got from the documentation from react router Dom it states the error above when trying to go to the private route.

A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes>
element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a
<Routes>.



Tried using the direct code from React-Router-DOM's docs and made sure that the localStorage is storing an ID on login.
